# Can I stop casper.fetchText from removing <br> automatically?

Tags: javascript, parsing, text, casperjs

`casper.fetchText` seems to automatically remove `<br>` in the fetched text.

e.g. if the text is `abc<br>de`, then `casper.fetchText` will return `abcde` instead of `abc<br>de`.

Is there any way to keep it as `abc<br>de`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to preserve `<br>` is to retrieve the element's representation as HTML.

There are several ways. `casper.fetchText()` concatenates the text content of all matched element. That's also exactly what `element.textContent` does, but only for one element.

You can use [`casper.getHTML()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#gethtml) to retrieve the `element.innerHTML` of a single element:

```
var content = casper.getHTML(selector);
```

If you want the same behavior as `fetchText` which concatenates all elements' values, then you need to do it yourself like this:

```
var contents = casper.getElementsInfo(selector).map(function(e){
    return e.html;
}).join("\n");
```

[`casper.getElementsInfo()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementsinfo) provides the `html` property for each element. The `map` creates an array only containing the `html` strings and `join` makes a single string out of it.

Comment: yes getHTML() is the function I am looking for, thanks!